# file paths been passed to a Json Array

Tags: c++, phonegap-plugins, arrays

I want to allow a user to specify a file path to attach to an email.

e.g.

```
/documents/myfile.dat
```

index.html

```
<label>Attachment:</label><input id="attachmentType" type="text"/>
```

index.js

```
var jsonEmail =
{
...
"attachment": document.getElementById('attachmentType').value
}
```

.cpp

```
Json::Value input;
bool parse = reader.parse(inputString, input);
if(parse){
  ...
  Json::Value msgAtt = input["attachment"];
  ...
  if(msgAtt.isArray()){
    foreach(Json::Value v, msgAtt){
     do something here...
    }
  }
  else{
    QString filePath = QString::fromStdString(msgAtt.asString());
    do some more stuff here...
  }
```

This works fine and has the proper path. The problem I have is when I send multiple file paths:

```
/sdcard/documents/myfile.dat, /sdcard/documents/nextfile.dat
```

The Json value is never recognized as an array.  I know that I can read through the path and pull out data as needed, but I am hoping that this can be handled in the way that the data is passed and/or read?

Comment: how are you passing the data?  For passing data as an array using JSON, it should be if the following format: [data, data]. So from your example, assuming the path are strings, the data should be like the following: ['sdcard/document/myfile.data', '/sdcard/documents/nextfile.data']

Comment: @T.V. Yes, that fixed it.  I was passing the paths without the ' around the path.  I had tried using a " previously, but that did not work.  But then why do email addresses work without the ' around them?

Comment: I'm not sure why the email addresses are working as I don't have the full picture of what your code and the data that's being passed looks like but in general, if a value is a string then it should have quotes, either ' or ", around it

Comment: @T.V. actually, it did not work.  The ' is included as part of the string. I added some more code above if that helps.

Comment: ah I see, so you taking a input from the user's browser, in that case you need to transform you value into an array if you want your code to consider it as an array.  You can change
document.getElementById('attachmentType').value
in your js file to
document.getElementById('attachmentType').value.split(',')
that will create an array of filepaths. This is assuming that each value is separated by a comma.

Comment: But what happens if there is a legitimate ',' in the path?  I know that it is rare, but it is possible.  Also, again back to email addresses. I enter 2 email addresses separated by a ',' and use the same process as above for the attachments and it recognizes that this is an array?